# asyncio terminate subprocess on timeout

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-asyncio

I have a script which must execute some shell commands. However if command takes too long to complete it must be forcibly killed. Consider the following code snippet:

```
import asyncio, random

q = asyncio.Queue()

MAX_WAIT = 5

@asyncio.coroutine
def blocking_task(sec):
    print('This task will sleep {} sec.'.format(sec))
    create = asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
       'sleep {s}; echo "Woke up after {s} sec." >> ./tst.log'.format(s=sec),
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    proc = yield from create
    yield from proc.wait()

@asyncio.coroutine
def produce():
    while True:
        q.put_nowait(random.randint(3,8))
        yield from asyncio.sleep(0.5 + random.random())

@asyncio.coroutine
def consume():
    while True:
        value = yield from q.get()
        try:
            yield from asyncio.wait_for(blocking_task(value), MAX_WAIT)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print('~/~ Job has been cancelled !!')
        else:
            print('=/= Job has been done :]')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(produce())
asyncio.ensure_future(consume())
loop.run_forever()
```

This code produce the following output:

```
This task will sleep 4 sec.
=/= Job has been done :]
This task will sleep 8 sec.
~/~ Job has been cancelled !!
This task will sleep 5 sec.
~/~ Job has been cancelled !!
```

So it seems that it's working as expected, jobs are stopped if they take too long to finish. But if I check the log I can confirm that however time consuming tasks continued running and were not actually stopped / killed / aborted:

```
Woke up after 4 sec.
Woke up after 8 sec.
Woke up after 5 sec.
```

I would expect there should be just one line in the log, as other processes must have been aborted before they had a chance to finish:

```
Woke up after 4 sec.
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

I'm not even sure if I need `asyncio` here, perhaps `concurrent.futures` could be used too. Either way task is the same - terminate tasks, which are taking too much time to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Process.terminate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.asyncio.subprocess.Process.terminate):

```
try:
    yield from proc.wait()
except asyncio.CancelledError:
    proc.terminate()
    raise
```

Or:

```
try:
    yield from proc.wait()
finally:
    if proc.returncode is None:
        proc.terminate()
```

---

EDIT

> Why I didn't see asyncio.CancelledError raised in my code?

When `asyncio.wait_for` (or anything else) cancels a task, it throws a `CancelledError` in the corresponding coroutine. This allows the coroutine to perform some clean up if necessary (using a context manager or a `try/finally` clause for instance). This error does not need to be logged since it is the normal behavior of a canceled task. But try to await a task after cancelling it and a `CancelledError` will be raised.

Comment: That worked really beautifully, thank you! I just don't quite understand, why I didn't see `asyncio.CancelledError` raised in my code? The output was clean as shown, without any exceptions.

Comment: in your first example, what will raise `CancelledError`? Looks like `proc.wait()` will wait forever if the process doesn't die.

Comment: @Rugnar `asyncio.wait_for` calls [task.cancel](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) which causes the task to stop its current operation with a `CancelledError`.